# How do I create a jupyter_notebook_config.py file?

Tags: jupyter

I'm trying to set up Jupyter access via password (rather than token), but I have a problem following the documentation, which says
    you can use the following command line:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

However, I don't seem to have a `jupyter` command, and searching my Windows machine doesn't turn up anything like `jupyter.exe`.  How do I do this, then?

Comment: Eh... have you installed Jupyter at all? https://jupyter.org/install I recommend to use Miniconda and create a dedicated conda environment for your installation.

Comment: Yes, I can start Jupyter notebook.